# How to achieve the same thing for the Facebook API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Reading on this [oauth tutorial](http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/twitter-oauth-and-ruby-on-rails-integrated-cookbook-style-in-the-console-updated-for-twitter-1-0/).

The code below, shows how this can be achieved to get the access tokens on Twitter's API. I would like to do exactly the same thing for the Facebook API using OAuth.

```
#oauth = OAuth::Consumer.new(APP_CONFIG['twitter_consumer_key'], APP_CONFIG['twitter_consumer_secret'], :site => 'http://api.twitter.com', :request_endpoint => 'http://api.twitter.com', :sign_in => true)

# Get the request tokens from the API
rt = oauth.get_request_token
rtoken = rt.token # request token
rsecret = rt.secret # request token secret

# Go to url and click ""Allow access” when prompted
# http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=your_request_token_from_above

# Get the access tokens from the API
at = rt.get_access_token
oauth_token = at.token
oauth_token_secret = at.secret
```

Anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at "OAuth URLs and tokens" on the Koala docs: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth It is a great gem for FB.